# Count unique values in nested key // array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Aim**

I would like to count how many unique `detail.id` or `groupDocs.id` there are.
I can either count it through initial `data` (`detail.id`) or through the result of `groupDocs` (`groupDocs.id`). Both are in the code snippet at the bottom.

**Things I've tried and that didn't work**

```
  const v1 = new Set(data.map(i => i.details.id))
  console.log("v1: ", v1);

  const v2 = [...new Set(groupDocs)];
  console.log("v2: ", v2);

  const v3 = data.reduce((total, el) => {
    el.details.forEach((el) => {
      if (el in total) total[el]++;
      else total[el] = 1;
    });
    return total;
  }, {});

  console.log("v3: ", v3);
```

**Here is the code snippet that contain the original `data`, the array manipulation `groupDocs` and my failed attempts**

```js
  const data = [
    {
      id: 222222,
      document_file_name: "4020653_FileName.pdf",
      document_url: "www.",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "accepted",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        },
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1111111,
      document_file_name: "4020600_FileName.pdf",
      document_url: "www.",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 2000,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        },
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 333333,
      document_file_name: "4020890_FileName.pdf",
      document_url: "www.",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 444444,
      document_file_name: "4020672_FileName.pdf",
      document_url: "www.",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Other",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const groupDocs = [
    ...data
      .reduce(
        (
          travelDocsMap,
          {
            id: travel_doc_id,
            document_file_name,
            document_type_label,
            document_url,
            state,
            details = []
          }
        ) => {
          let details_ids = details.map((o) => o.id).sort();
          const details_ids_unique = details_ids.join("_"),
            type = details.map((o) => o.type),
            name = details.map((o) => o.name);
          if (details_ids.length === 1) {
            details_ids = details_ids[0];
          }

          const details_g = travelDocsMap.get(details_ids_unique) ?? {
            id: details_ids,
            type,
            name,
            docs: []
          };
          details_g.docs.push({
            travel_doc_id,
            document_file_name,
            document_type_label,
            document_url,
            state
          });
          travelDocsMap.set(details_ids_unique, details_g);
          return travelDocsMap;
        },
        new Map()
      )
      .values()
  ];
  console.log("groupDocs: ", groupDocs);




  const v1 = new Set(data.map(i => i.details.id))
  console.log("v1: ", v1);

  const v2 = [...new Set(groupDocs)];
  console.log("v2: ", v2);

  const v3 = data.reduce((total, el) => {
   el.details.forEach((el) => {
    if (el in total) total[el]++;
    else total[el] = 1;
  });
  return total;
  }, {});

  console.log("v3: ", v3);
```

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: you can obtain `details` ids with `data.flatMap(x => x.details.map(d => d.id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```js
const result = new Set(data.flatMap(d => d.details.map(de => de.id)));
console.log(result);
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).